# FirebaseFirestore.getInstance() and app has stoped

Tags: android, firebase

I run my Android app (based on Java), and it works.
Next, I add to my app code:

FirebaseFirestore fdb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();

This code I got from the official Android site
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

App runs, but next the running device shows the message "app has stopped".

I use a device simulator available in Android Studio.

It is my first Android app, and I can't understand what is going.

----Trace------
2021-06-08 20:57:30.186 7155-7155/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
2021-06-08 20:57:30.188 7155-7155/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
2021-06-08 20:57:30.210 7155-7155/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-06-08 20:57:30.214 7155-7155/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
2021-06-08 20:57:30.229 7155-7155/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
2021-06-08 20:57:30.229 7155-7155/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
2021-06-08 20:57:30.230 7155-7155/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
2021-06-08 20:57:30.239 7155-7155/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am

```
--------- beginning of system
```

2021-06-08 20:57:30.243 1598-2008/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.ftc appid=10080 user=0: from pid 7155
2021-06-08 20:57:30.245 7155-7155/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-06-08 20:57:30.249 1806-1806/? D/CarrierSvcBindHelper: No carrier app for: 0
2021-06-08 20:57:30.517 7165-7165/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
2021-06-08 20:57:30.520 7165-7165/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
2021-06-08 20:57:30.543 7171-7171/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
2021-06-08 20:57:30.546 7171-7171/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
2021-06-08 20:57:30.549 7165-7165/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-06-08 20:57:30.552 7165-7165/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
2021-06-08 20:57:30.565 7165-7165/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
2021-06-08 20:57:30.565 7165-7165/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
2021-06-08 20:57:30.565 7165-7165/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
2021-06-08 20:57:30.569 7171-7171/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-06-08 20:57:30.573 7171-7171/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
2021-06-08 20:57:30.574 7165-7165/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.wm.Wm
2021-06-08 20:57:30.575 7165-7165/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-06-08 20:57:30.598 7171-7171/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
2021-06-08 20:57:30.598 7171-7171/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
2021-06-08 20:57:30.598 7171-7171/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
2021-06-08 20:57:30.607 7171-7171/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
2021-06-08 20:57:30.611 1598-2050/? I/ActivityManager: Force stopping com.ftc appid=10080 user=0: from pid 7171
2021-06-08 20:57:30.611 7171-7171/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-06-08 20:57:30.616 1806-1806/? D/CarrierSvcBindHelper: No carrier app for: 0
2021-06-08 20:57:30.901 7192-7192/? D/AndroidRuntime: >>>>>> START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit uid 2000 <<<<<<
2021-06-08 20:57:30.903 7192-7192/? D/AndroidRuntime: CheckJNI is ON
2021-06-08 20:57:30.926 7192-7192/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-06-08 20:57:30.930 7192-7192/? D/ICU: No timezone override file found: /data/misc/zoneinfo/current/icu/icu_tzdata.dat
2021-06-08 20:57:30.949 7192-7192/? E/memtrack: Couldn't load memtrack module (No such file or directory)
2021-06-08 20:57:30.949 7192-7192/? E/android.os.Debug: failed to load memtrack module: -2
2021-06-08 20:57:30.950 7192-7192/? I/Radio-JNI: register_android_hardware_Radio DONE
2021-06-08 20:57:30.959 7192-7192/? D/AndroidRuntime: Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am
2021-06-08 20:57:30.964 1598-2808/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.ftc/.MainActivity} from uid 2000 on display 0
2021-06-08 20:57:30.973 7192-7192/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
2021-06-08 20:57:30.978 7203-7203/? I/art: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
2021-06-08 20:57:30.979 7203-7203/? W/art: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
2021-06-08 20:57:30.985 1598-2050/? I/ActivityManager: Start proc 7203:com.ftc/u0a80 for activity com.ftc/.MainActivity
2021-06-08 20:57:31.011 1311-1350/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 2789376
2021-06-08 20:57:31.028 1311-1311/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1311: eglCreateSyncKHR(1901): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
2021-06-08 20:57:31.076 1311-1350/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8294400
2021-06-08 20:57:31.150 7203-7203/com.ftc W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.ftc-1/lib/x86
2021-06-08 20:57:31.176 5525-5542/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa648ec20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa81b8ac0)
2021-06-08 20:57:31.189 7203-7203/com.ftc W/FirebaseApp: Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options were found. This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services was not applied to your gradle project.
2021-06-08 20:57:31.191 7203-7203/com.ftc I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization unsuccessful
2021-06-08 20:57:31.210 1311-2977/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8294400
2021-06-08 20:57:31.222 7203-7203/com.ftc D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

```
--------- beginning of crash
```

2021-06-08 20:57:31.223 7203-7203/com.ftc E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.ftc, PID: 7203
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.ftc/com.ftc.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.ftc. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2548)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.ftc. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first.
at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(FirebaseApp.java:183)
at com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore.getInstance(FirebaseFirestore.java:95)
at com.ftc.MainActivity.(MainActivity.java:54)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2538)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
2021-06-08 20:57:31.227 1598-2007/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.ftc/.MainActivity
2021-06-08 20:57:31.238 1598-2007/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity com.ftc/.MainActivity
2021-06-08 20:57:31.238 1598-2007/? W/ActivityManager: Duplicate finish request for ActivityRecord{90226b6 u0 com.ftc/.MainActivity t37 f}
2021-06-08 20:57:31.288 1311-1318/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8294400
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8669): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/1" dev="proc" ino=3125 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8670): avc: denied { search } for name="1" dev="proc" ino=3125 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8671): avc: denied { search } for name="1" dev="proc" ino=3125 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:init:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8672): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/2" dev="proc" ino=6987 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8673): avc: denied { search } for name="2" dev="proc" ino=6987 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8674): avc: denied { search } for name="2" dev="proc" ino=6987 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8675): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/3" dev="proc" ino=6988 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8676): avc: denied { search } for name="3" dev="proc" ino=6988 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8677): avc: denied { search } for name="3" dev="proc" ino=6988 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8678): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/5" dev="proc" ino=6990 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8679): avc: denied { search } for name="5" dev="proc" ino=6990 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8680): avc: denied { search } for name="5" dev="proc" ino=6990 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8681): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/7" dev="proc" ino=6992 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8682): avc: denied { search } for name="7" dev="proc" ino=6992 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8683): avc: denied { search } for name="7" dev="proc" ino=6992 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8684): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/8" dev="proc" ino=6993 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8685): avc: denied { search } for name="8" dev="proc" ino=6993 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8686): avc: denied { search } for name="8" dev="proc" ino=6993 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8687): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/9" dev="proc" ino=6994 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8688): avc: denied { search } for name="9" dev="proc" ino=6994 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8689): avc: denied { search } for name="9" dev="proc" ino=6994 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8690): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/10" dev="proc" ino=6995 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8691): avc: denied { search } for name="10" dev="proc" ino=6995 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8692): avc: denied { search } for name="10" dev="proc" ino=6995 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8693): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/11" dev="proc" ino=6996 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8694): avc: denied { search } for name="11" dev="proc" ino=6996 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8695): avc: denied { search } for name="11" dev="proc" ino=6996 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8696): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/12" dev="proc" ino=6997 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8697): avc: denied { search } for name="12" dev="proc" ino=6997 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8698): avc: denied { search } for name="12" dev="proc" ino=6997 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8699): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/13" dev="proc" ino=6998 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8700): avc: denied { search } for name="13" dev="proc" ino=6998 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8701): avc: denied { search } for name="13" dev="proc" ino=6998 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8702): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/14" dev="proc" ino=6999 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8703): avc: denied { search } for name="14" dev="proc" ino=6999 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8704): avc: denied { search } for name="14" dev="proc" ino=6999 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8705): avc: denied { getattr } for path="/proc/15" dev="proc" ino=7000 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.346 7223-7223/? W/ps: type=1400 audit(0.0:8706): avc: denied { search } for name="15" dev="proc" ino=7000 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:kernel:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.705 1598-1637/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2021-06-08 20:57:31.705 1598-1637/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
2021-06-08 20:57:31.705 1598-1637/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
2021-06-08 20:57:31.705 1598-1637/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
2021-06-08 20:57:31.727 1598-1637/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0x9b6b2360: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
2021-06-08 20:57:31.732 1598-1637/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b6b2360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa81fe500)
2021-06-08 20:57:31.740 1598-1611/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{90226b6 u0 com.ftc/.MainActivity t37 f}
2021-06-08 20:57:31.805 1598-1637/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b6b2360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa81fe500)
2021-06-08 20:57:31.833 1311-2977/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 2691072
2021-06-08 20:57:31.959 1311-1311/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1311: eglCreateSyncKHR(1901): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
2021-06-08 20:57:31.974 1598-1608/? D/WindowManager: relayoutVisibleWindow: Window{8409536 u0 logifact.terminal.terminalandroid/logifact.terminal.terminalandroid.FullscreenActivity EXITING} mAnimatingExit=true, mRemoveOnExit=false, mDestroying=false
2021-06-08 20:57:32.387 5525-5525/? I/Choreographer: Skipped 37 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-06-08 20:57:32.479 5525-5542/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa648ec20: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa81b8ac0)
2021-06-08 20:57:32.605 1598-1618/? I/Choreographer: Skipped 35 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-06-08 20:57:32.696 1598-1612/? I/Choreographer: Skipped 55 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
2021-06-08 20:57:32.739 1598-1618/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Starting com.ftc) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2016 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:882 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.removeLocked:1456 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindowInnerLocked:2484 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowToken.destroySurfaces:365 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.finishExit:565 com.android.server.wm.AppWindowAnimator.stepAnimationLocked:427 com.android.server.wm.WindowAnimator.updateAppWindowsLocked:176
2021-06-08 20:57:32.746 1598-1611/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 6775:com.android.defcontainer/u0a8 (adj 906): empty for 2052s
2021-06-08 20:57:32.749 1598-2808/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 6775
2021-06-08 20:57:32.757 1598-1618/? W/WindowManager: Failed looking up window
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Requested window android.view.ViewRootImpl$W@c774eaf does not exist
at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9107)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.windowForClientLocked(WindowManagerService.java:9098)
at com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.removeWindow(WindowManagerService.java:2302)
at com.android.server.wm.Session.remove(Session.java:202)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.dispatchDetachedFromWindow(ViewRootImpl.java:3286)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doDie(ViewRootImpl.java:5881)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3622)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
at com.android.server.ServiceThread.run(ServiceThread.java:46)
2021-06-08 20:57:42.755 1598-1611/? W/ActivityManager: Activity destroy timeout for ActivityRecord{90226b6 u0 com.ftc/.MainActivity t37 f}
2021-06-08 20:58:04.924 1311-1318/? E/SurfaceFlinger: ro.sf.lcd_density must be defined as a build property
2021-06-08 20:58:04.924 1311-1349/? D/PermissionCache: checking android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER for uid=2000 => granted (279 us)
2021-06-08 20:58:04.943 1311-1349/? D/gralloc_ranchu: gralloc_alloc: Creating ashmem region of size 8294400
2021-06-08 20:58:05.020 1311-1311/? E/EGL_emulation: tid 1311: eglCreateSyncKHR(1901): error 0x3004 (EGL_BAD_ATTRIBUTE)
2021-06-08 20:59:40.108 1598-1610/? I/UsageStatsService: User[0] Flushing usage stats to disk
2021-06-08 21:02:31.272 1598-2007/? I/ActivityManager: Killing 7203:com.ftc/u0a80 (adj 900): crash
2021-06-08 21:02:31.272 1598-2007/? D/ActivityManager: cleanUpApplicationRecord -- 7203
2021-06-08 21:02:31.276 1598-1637/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0x9b6b2360: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa81fe500)
2021-06-08 21:02:31.287 1598-1608/? W/InputMethodManagerService: Window already focused, ignoring focus gain of: com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodClient$Stub$Proxy@69c5a50 attribute=null, token = android.os.BinderProxy@ef116d1
2021-06-08 21:02:31.471 1598-1618/? I/WindowManager: Destroying surface Surface(name=Application Error: com.ftc) called by com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurface:2016 com.android.server.wm.WindowStateAnimator.destroySurfaceLocked:882 com.android.server.wm.WindowState.destroyOrSaveSurface:2100 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementInner:429 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacementLoop:232 com.android.server.wm.WindowSurfacePlacer.performSurfacePlacement:180 com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService$H.handleMessage:8086 android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage:102
2021-06-08 21:02:31.472 1598-1618/? W/AppOps: Finishing op nesting under-run: uid 1000 pkg android code 24 time=0 duration=0 nesting=0
2021-06-08 21:06:13.985 1598-1645/? D/WifiNative-HAL: Failing getSupportedFeatureset because HAL isn't started
2021-06-08 21:06:13.986 1598-1614/? E/BluetoothAdapter: Bluetooth binder is null
2021-06-08 21:06:13.987 1598-1614/? E/BatteryStatsService: no controller energy info supplied
2021-06-08 21:06:13.990 1598-1614/? E/KernelCpuSpeedReader: Failed to read cpu-freq: /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/stats/time_in_state (No such file or directory)
2021-06-08 21:06:13.990 1598-1614/? E/KernelUidCpuTimeReader: Failed to read uid_cputime: /proc/uid_cputime/show_uid_stat (No such file or directory)
2021-06-08 21:06:13.990 1598-1614/? E/BatteryStatsService: modem info is invalid: ModemActivityInfo{ mTimestamp=0 mSleepTimeMs=0 mIdleTimeMs=0 mTxTimeMs[]=[0, 0, 0, 0, 0] mRxTimeMs=0 mEnergyUsed=0}
2021-06-08 21:06:24.160 1598-1598/? I/EntropyMixer: Writing entropy...
2021-06-08 21:06:48.148 2173-7243/? I/EventLogChimeraService: Aggregate from 1623173499295 (log), 1623173499295 (data)
2021-06-08 21:07:45.044 1598-1611/? I/ProcessStatsService: Prepared write state in 6ms
2021-06-08 21:08:40.343 1962-7249/? W/ConfigurationChimeraPro: Got null configs for com.google.android.gms.tapandpay_legacy_gservices
2021-06-08 21:08:40.344 1962-7249/? I/PaymentBundleManager: Maintaining payment bundles
2021-06-08 21:08:40.357 1962-7249/? I/PaymentBundleManager: Finished maintaining payment bundles
2021-06-08 21:08:40.502 1962-2753/? E/NetworkScheduler: ignoring stale queue check message
2021-06-08 21:08:40.644 1962-7250/? I/GoogleURLConnFactory: Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
2021-06-08 21:08:40.646 1962-7250/? I/GoogleURLConnFactory: Using platform SSLCertificateSocketFactory
2021-06-08 21:09:02.321 1962-7065/? V/NativeCrypto: Read error: ssl=0x8efc2000: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
2021-06-08 21:09:02.323 1962-7065/? V/NativeCrypto: SSL shutdown failed: ssl=0x8efc2000: I/O error during system call, Broken pipe
2021-06-08 21:09:02.324 1598-2778/? D/ConnectivityService: reportNetworkConnectivity(100, false) by 10013
2021-06-08 21:09:16.466 1598-1654/? D/ConnectivityService: NetworkAgentInfo [MOBILE (LTE) - 100] validation passed
2021-06-08 21:09:28.000 1598-1645/? I/WifiConnectivityManager: start a single scan from watchdogHandler
2021-06-08 21:09:28.000 1598-1645/? I/WifiConnectivityManager: scheduleWatchdogTimer

Comment: If the app crashes, there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: LogCat writes "No debuggable processes" and it shows empty body.

Comment: There should be for sure an Exception thrown. So there is a stack trace. Please look that up on logcat, and add it to your question.

Comment: I closed and opened again AS, and now I have the trace

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct Firebase dependencies?

Comment: Thanks, if I added apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' into app gradle file, app runs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your log, just before the initial crash. there is a warning:

> Default FirebaseApp failed to initialize because no default options
> were found.  This usually means that com.google.gms:google-services
> was not applied to your gradle project.

simply adding `com.google.gms:google-services` should fix any issues you have, if you have issues, ensure your Gradle cache is cleared or run without the build cache
`--no-build-cache`