# Unable to save firebase firestore with kotlin android

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

Now I'm running the firebase firestore example code.

Then failed to save and tried debugging using the println() function.

The debug results are output 1, 2, 3, 8.

The db.collection ("users") part is not running.

```
val firebaseTest:Button = findViewById(R.id.firebaseTest)
        firebaseTest.setOnClickListener {
            println(1)
            val db = Firebase.firestore
            println(2)
            // Create a new user with a first and last name
            val user = hashMapOf(
                "first" to "Ada",
                "last" to "Lovelace",
                "born" to 1815
            )

            println(3)
// Add a new document with a generated ID
            db.collection("users")
                .add(user)
                .addOnSuccessListener { documentReference ->
                    println(4)
                    Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "success.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    println(5)
                }
                .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                    println(6)
                    Toast.makeText(this@LoginActivity, "faild", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    println(7)
                }
            println(8)
        }
```

Comment: The expected output would be `1, 2, 3, 8, 4, 5` or `1, 2, 3, 8, 6, 7`  If not, the problem is elsewhere in your code like not initialising Firebase correctly. Check the logs from when you start the app.

Comment: Please edit your question and tell us what is the output that you get in the logcat using the shared code.  Please also respond with @

Comment: @samthecodingman Could you tell me what part of the log I have to look at?

Comment: @AlexMamo I'm a beginner, so I don't know how to look at the logcat.
However, the next log will continue to be output.

2021-06-11 00:56:47.469 1785-2320/? E/GnssHAL_GnssInterface: gnssSvStatusCb: b: input svInfo.flags is 8

Comment: I already answered that - "Check the logs from when you start the app". You will probably find an error similar to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67897234/3068190). To do so you will need to look up how to read a logcat.